# Training CNN on Matlab gives different results compared to training the same network on python using keras

Tags: python, matlab, keras, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

I'm using Keras to train a netwok for classification problem on python, the model that i am using is as follows:

```
filter_size = (2,2)
maxpool_size = (2, 2)
dr = 0.5

inputs = Input((12,8,1), name='main_input')

main_branch = Conv2D(20, kernel_size=filter_size, padding="same", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(inputs)
main_branch = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)(main_branch)
main_branch = Activation("relu")(main_branch)
main_branch = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=maxpool_size,strides=(1, 1))(main_branch)

main_branch = Conv2D(40, kernel_size=filter_size, padding="same", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(main_branch)
main_branch = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)(main_branch)
main_branch = Activation("relu")(main_branch)

main_branch = Flatten()(main_branch)
main_branch = Dense(100,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(main_branch)
main_branch = Dense(100, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(main_branch)

SubArray_branch = Dense(496, activation='softmax', name='SubArray_output')(main_branch)
model = Model(inputs = inputs,
     outputs =  SubArray_branch)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss={'SubArray_output': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics=['accuracy'] )
 history =  model.fit({'main_input': Channel},
              {'SubArray_output': array_indx},
              validation_data=(test_Data,test_array),
              epochs=100, batch_size=128,
              verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.2
             )
```

when I am training this network on my training data I get high validation-loss compared to training-loss as you can see in below:

```
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5723 - accuracy: 0.9010 - val_loss: 20.2040 - val_accuracy: 0.0126
Epoch 33/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5486 - accuracy: 0.9087 - val_loss: 35.2516 - val_accuracy: 0.0037
Epoch 34/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5342 - accuracy: 0.9159 - val_loss: 50.2577 - val_accuracy: 0.0043
Epoch 35/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5345 - accuracy: 0.9132 - val_loss: 26.0221 - val_accuracy: 0.0051
Epoch 36/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5333 - accuracy: 0.9140 - val_loss: 71.2754 - val_accuracy: 0.0043
Epoch 37/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5149 - accuracy: 0.9231 - val_loss: 67.2646 - val_accuracy: 3.3227e-04
Epoch 38/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5269 - accuracy: 0.9162 - val_loss: 17.7448 - val_accuracy: 0.0206
Epoch 39/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5198 - accuracy: 0.9201 - val_loss: 92.7240 - val_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 40/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5157 - accuracy: 0.9247 - val_loss: 30.9589 - val_accuracy: 0.0082
Epoch 41/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4961 - accuracy: 0.9316 - val_loss: 20.0444 - val_accuracy: 0.0141
Epoch 42/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5093 - accuracy: 0.9256 - val_loss: 16.7269 - val_accuracy: 0.0172
Epoch 43/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5092 - accuracy: 0.9267 - val_loss: 15.6939 - val_accuracy: 0.0320
Epoch 44/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5104 - accuracy: 0.9270 - val_loss: 103.2581 - val_accuracy: 0.0027
Epoch 45/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5074 - accuracy: 0.9286 - val_loss: 28.3097 - val_accuracy: 0.0154
Epoch 46/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4977 - accuracy: 0.9303 - val_loss: 28.6676 - val_accuracy: 0.0167
Epoch 47/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4823 - accuracy: 0.9375 - val_loss: 47.4671 - val_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 48/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5053 - accuracy: 0.9291 - val_loss: 39.3356 - val_accuracy: 0.0082
Epoch 49/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5110 - accuracy: 0.9287 - val_loss: 42.8834 - val_accuracy: 0.0082
Epoch 50/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4895 - accuracy: 0.9366 - val_loss: 11.7254 - val_accuracy: 0.0700
Epoch 51/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4909 - accuracy: 0.9351 - val_loss: 14.5519 - val_accuracy: 0.0276
Epoch 52/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4846 - accuracy: 0.9380 - val_loss: 22.5101 - val_accuracy: 0.0122
Epoch 53/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4991 - accuracy: 0.9315 - val_loss: 16.1494 - val_accuracy: 0.0283
Epoch 54/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4782 - accuracy: 0.9423 - val_loss: 14.8626 - val_accuracy: 0.0551
Epoch 55/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4807 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 100.8670 - val_accuracy: 9.9681e-04
Epoch 56/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4759 - accuracy: 0.9420 - val_loss: 34.8571 - val_accuracy: 0.0047
Epoch 57/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4802 - accuracy: 0.9406 - val_loss: 23.2134 - val_accuracy: 0.0524
Epoch 58/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4998 - accuracy: 0.9334 - val_loss: 20.9038 - val_accuracy: 0.0207
Epoch 59/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4813 - accuracy: 0.9400 - val_loss: 19.5474 - val_accuracy: 0.0393
Epoch 60/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4846 - accuracy: 0.9399 - val_loss: 15.1594 - val_accuracy: 0.0439
Epoch 61/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4718 - accuracy: 0.9436 - val_loss: 30.0164 - val_accuracy: 0.0078
Epoch 62/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4897 - accuracy: 0.9375 - val_loss: 60.0498 - val_accuracy: 0.0144
Epoch 63/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4668 - accuracy: 0.9461 - val_loss: 18.8190 - val_accuracy: 0.0298
Epoch 64/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4598 - accuracy: 0.9485 - val_loss: 26.1101 - val_accuracy: 0.0231
Epoch 65/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4672 - accuracy: 0.9442 - val_loss: 108.7207 - val_accuracy: 2.6582e-04
Epoch 66/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4910 - accuracy: 0.9378 - val_loss: 45.6070 - val_accuracy: 0.0052
Epoch 67/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4805 - accuracy: 0.9429 - val_loss: 39.3904 - val_accuracy: 0.0057
Epoch 68/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4682 - accuracy: 0.9451 - val_loss: 21.5525 - val_accuracy: 0.0328
Epoch 69/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4613 - accuracy: 0.9472 - val_loss: 46.7714 - val_accuracy: 0.0027
Epoch 70/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4786 - accuracy: 0.9417 - val_loss: 13.4834 - val_accuracy: 0.0708
Epoch 71/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4756 - accuracy: 0.9442 - val_loss: 41.8796 - val_accuracy: 0.0199
Epoch 72/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4655 - accuracy: 0.9464 - val_loss: 57.7453 - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 73/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4795 - accuracy: 0.9428 - val_loss: 16.1949 - val_accuracy: 0.0285
Epoch 74/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4755 - accuracy: 0.9440 - val_loss: 68.2349 - val_accuracy: 0.0139
Epoch 75/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4807 - accuracy: 0.9425 - val_loss: 43.4699 - val_accuracy: 0.0233
Epoch 76/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4515 - accuracy: 0.9524 - val_loss: 175.2205 - val_accuracy: 0.0019
Epoch 77/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4715 - accuracy: 0.9467 - val_loss: 92.2833 - val_accuracy: 0.0017
Epoch 78/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4736 - accuracy: 0.9447 - val_loss: 94.7209 - val_accuracy: 0.0059
Epoch 79/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4661 - accuracy: 0.9473 - val_loss: 17.8870 - val_accuracy: 0.0386
Epoch 80/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4614 - accuracy: 0.9492 - val_loss: 28.1883 - val_accuracy: 0.0042
Epoch 81/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4569 - accuracy: 0.9507 - val_loss: 49.2823 - val_accuracy: 0.0032
Epoch 82/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4623 - accuracy: 0.9485 - val_loss: 29.8972 - val_accuracy: 0.0100
Epoch 83/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4799 - accuracy: 0.9429 - val_loss: 109.5044 - val_accuracy: 0.0062
Epoch 84/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4810 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 71.2103 - val_accuracy: 0.0051
Epoch 85/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4452 - accuracy: 0.9552 - val_loss: 30.7861 - val_accuracy: 0.0100
Epoch 86/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4805 - accuracy: 0.9423 - val_loss: 48.1887 - val_accuracy: 0.0031
Epoch 87/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4564 - accuracy: 0.9512 - val_loss: 189.6711 - val_accuracy: 1.3291e-04
Epoch 88/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4479 - accuracy: 0.9537 - val_loss: 58.6349 - val_accuracy: 0.0199
Epoch 89/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4667 - accuracy: 0.9476 - val_loss: 95.7323 - val_accuracy: 0.0041
Epoch 90/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4808 - accuracy: 0.9436 - val_loss: 28.7513 - val_accuracy: 0.0191
Epoch 91/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4583 - accuracy: 0.9511 - val_loss: 16.4281 - val_accuracy: 0.0431
Epoch 92/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4458 - accuracy: 0.9541 - val_loss: 15.3890 - val_accuracy: 0.0517
Epoch 93/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4628 - accuracy: 0.9491 - val_loss: 37.3123 - val_accuracy: 0.0024
Epoch 94/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4716 - accuracy: 0.9481 - val_loss: 24.8934 - val_accuracy: 0.0123
Epoch 95/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4646 - accuracy: 0.9469 - val_loss: 54.6682 - val_accuracy: 5.9809e-04
Epoch 96/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4665 - accuracy: 0.9492 - val_loss: 89.1835 - val_accuracy: 0.0064
Epoch 97/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.4533 - accuracy: 0.9527 - val_loss: 60.9850 - val_accuracy: 0.0035
Epoch 98/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4597 - accuracy: 0.9491 - val_loss: 41.6088 - val_accuracy: 0.0023
Epoch 99/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4511 - accuracy: 0.9537 - val_loss: 28.2131 - val_accuracy: 0.0025
Epoch 100/100
471/471 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4568 - accuracy: 0.9509 - val_loss: 121.8944 - val_accuracy: 0.0041
```

I am well aware that the problem I am facing is due to overfitting, but when I train the same network with the same training data on Matlab, the values of training-loss and validation-loss are close to each other. The picture of Training Progress on Matlab is linked as:
[Training Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nNqt.png)

I would appreciate it, if anyone could explain to me why I can’t get the same result on python? What would you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem. My guess is probably the data in matlab isn't the same format as in python. How do you load and reshape the data for keras?

Comment: Hi, I have not fully figured it out myself, but as far as I know, python is more reliable than Matlab for DL and ML. as for my case, I think the problem was from the date structure and the relation between the input and output as it was too complex. I have generated the data in Matlab and loaded them onto python after constructing the network for training it. if you think more details about my problem could be useful, let me know about it.